# The BARE CXF web service invokes no parameter operation/method for GET request from web browsers

Tags: java, spring, web-services, cxf

I am not sure if this is a feature or bug introduced in version 2.7.1 (or greater) but below is the behavior I noticed when GET request is sent to the **BARE** CXF web service using web browsers.

**Code Snippets:**

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface HelloWorld 
{
    @WebMethod(action = "/sayHi")
    @WebResult(name = "strResponse", partName = "strResponse")
    public String sayHi();

    @WebMethod(action = "/sayHiToUser")
    @WebResult(name = "strResponse", partName = "strResponse")
    String sayHiToUser(@WebParam(name="user") String user);
}

@WebService
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld 
{
    @Override
    public String sayHi()
    {
        return "Hi there...";
    }

    @Override
    public String sayHiToUser(String user) 
    {
        return "Hi " + user;
    }
}

<jaxws:endpoint
    id="helloWorld"
    implementor="com.cxf.service.HelloWorldImpl"
    address="http://127.0.0.1:8080/HelloWorld" 
    endpointName="e:HelloWorld"
    xmlns:e="http://service.jaxws.cxf.apache.org/endpoint">
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

**Environment/Configs:**

• Java 1.6
• Spring 3.0.0
• CXF 2.7.0 / 2.7.1
• CXF web service starts within embedded Jetty using spring context

**Detailed Explanation:**

***CXF Version 2.7.0:***
When I access this web service using web browser with URL "http://127.0.0.1:8080/HelloWorld" (No ?wsdl at the end), I am getting "No such operation" response back in the web browser for both BARE & WRAPPED ParameterStyle which is the expected behavior.

***CXF Version 2.7.1 (or greater):***
*ParameterStyle **WRAPPED**:* When I access this web service using web browser with same URL as above (No ?wsdl at the end), I am getting "No binding operation info while invoking unknown method with params unknown." response back in the web browser which is the expected behavior.
*ParameterStyle **BARE**:* When I access this web service using web browser with URL as above (No ?wsdl at the end), I am getting "Hi there..." response back in the web browser. It calls sayHi() operation/method but there is no SOAPAction specified in the GET request header. This is NOT the expected response. I was expecting the same response as ParameterStyle WRAPPED.

**Results:**

*CXF Version: **2.7.0***
• URL: Same url as above (Using web browser and no ?wsdl at the end)
• ParameterStyle: BARE / Response: No such operation
• ParameterStyle: WRAPPED / Response: No such operation
• Expected Result? YES

*CXF Version: **2.7.1 (or greater)***
• URL: Same url as above (Using web browser and no ?wsdl at the end)
• ParameterStyle: BARE / Response: Hi there... / Called sayHi()
• ParameterStyle: WRAPPED / Response: No binding operation info while invoking unknown method with params unknown.
• Expected Result? NO. BARE should return the same result as WRAPPED

Answer (score 0):

From a 1st glance, this looks like the URIMappingInterceptor, see e.g. http://cxf.apache.org/cve-2012-5633.html, which was discarded again in later versions. Perhaps you loaded/added it to your setup by accident (or some defaults changed, not sure).

Btw: That CXF version is quite old (2012), I would highly recommend using a newer one, for both bug & security fixes.